# how to test my login page using phpunit in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, phpunit

I am new in phpUnit,my project is in codeigniter and i am using netbeans IDE 8.2 ,my os is windows10,i am trying to test my web site ,Now i have problem that how to test my login page?
i have tried this below code:

```php
class Welcome_test extends TestCase{
    public function addDataProvider(){
        return array(array('email'=>'abc@gmail.com','pass'=>'cdef'));
     }
    /*** @dataProvider addDataProvider*/
    public function test_login(){
        $output = $this->post('Login/submitlogin');
        $this->assertContains('<span class="title">Product List</span>',$output);
    }

}
```

i was expecting result should pass but unfortunately i am getting this error

> Welcome_test::test_login()
>   PHP Fatal error occured.
>   PHP Fatal error(s) occured, test results can be incomplete!
>   Review Output window for full output.'

Comment: Can you make the code more readable? Your entire question is a single paragraph.

Comment: now can any body help me?

Comment: Remove the quotes around your methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login page or any page so far can be tested using functional or acceptance testing using codeception.

unit testing helps us know if we are getting right assertions to our databases providing right data but they do not help us properly test the nature and functionality of page.

so I suggest you to use acceptance tests for this purpose.

Comment: ahmednawazbutt ,,thanks to pullout me from this problem,now i am using codeception and its working...